# Defining custom methods within a model/class in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, class-method

I have the following model:

```
class ActivityLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, presence: true
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, numericality: true

  def log
    ActivityLog.create(
      user_id: current_user ? current_user.id : -1,
      instance_id: instance_id,
      action: actions.index(action)
      )
  end

  private 

  def actions
    ['start','stop','create','destroy']
  end

end
```

When I call the following line from the rails console, I get an error:

```
ActivityLog.log(user_id: 1, instance_id:1, action: 'create')

# Error returned from console
NoMethodError: undefined method `log' for #<Class:0x007fb4755a26a8>
```

Why doesn't my method call work? I defined it in the class, but it says it is undefined. What am I missing or misunderstanding? Thank you.

Comment: you need to define the method as`self.log` to make it as a class method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Creating method `log`

Say you have a class `User`, and within the class, you define the method `has_cell_phone`. (The contents of that method does not matter.) When you define a method in a class as `def has_cell_phone`, that method can be called on any `User` object. While the `class User` is itself a *class* object, you would call it on an object whose immediate class is `User`. In correct terms, you would be writing an *instance method* for an *instance* of the `User` class.

You are getting that error because the method `log` you defined works only for an _instance of the `ActivityLog` class. If you do the following, you can call `log` correctly, given your current code:

```
activity_log = ActivityLog.create  # with required params
activity_log.log
```

Secondly, you are calling `log` with parameters, while your method definition does not require any. (That would look like `def log(params)`.)

Now, here is where you modify your existing code. When you want to call a method on the *entire* class (meaning the class itself), you prepend the keyword `self` to the class-method definition. For example, for the `User` class, it would be `def self.create_user_with_cell_phone`. You can also add arguments to that method. The arguments you provide in your "method call" line, I would add those to your class method, like so:

```
def self.log(instance_id, action)
  # ...
end

ActivityLog.log(1, 'create')
```

You would not need to include the `user_id`, because, based on your logic, it checks if the `current_user` object is `true`, and follows from there.

## Creating a class constant

A second look at your question, I found that you are defining a method `actions`. Remember what I said about instance methods? Since it appears that `actions` will always remain constant, I recommend that you make it one! To do so, it's recommended you place the following line in your class, before any method definitions.

```
ACTIONS = ['start','stop','create','destroy']
```

Then, any time you want to call `ACTIONS` while inside the `ActivityLog` class, you do the following: `ACTIONS.index(action)`. If you want to call this constant *outside* of its class, you would do this: `ActivityLog::ACTION`. It is *similar* syntax to a class-method call, instead you use `::` to separate the class from the constant. Re-examining your code, it should now look like this:

```
class ActivityLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  ACTIONS = ['start','stop','create','destroy']

  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, presence: true
  validates :user_id, :instance_id, :action, numericality: true

  def self.log(instance_id, action)
    ActivityLog.create(
      user_id: (current_user ? current_user.id : -1),
      instance_id: instance_id,
      action: ACTIONS.index(action)
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`log` is an instance method as defined; it will only work if you have a concrete instance of an `ActivityLog`.

If you want to make that a class method, you should attach it to the class via the `self` keyword.

```
def self.log
    # code here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing an instance method and calling it like a class method.

To write a class method, you need to add `self` before your method names (`self.log`, `self.actions`). This will let you call the method like you expect, and is probably the best way to write an alternate constructor like this. If your methods don't depend on a specific instance of the class, which it seems like you are doing here, then it is better to make them class methods.

Alternatively, you can create an instance of your class and call the instance methods you have defined. Instead of `ActivityLog.log`, make a new logger with `Activity.new` and call the log method on it. In one line, this would look like `Activity.new.log`, but you should probably store the new object in a variable to keep track of it.

One final alternative would be to use the `initialize` method. By writing `def initialize` you change the constructor for your class, so that instead of calling `ActivityLog.log` you can call `ActivityLog.new`. This makes it clearer that you are constructing a new object and is idiomatic in ruby. However, it does remove the descriptive method name. I would recommend this route if you aren't going to construct your class with any other methods, but if you want to have several, go with the class method.

Comment: I would disagree with `ActivityLog.new.log`, because the goal of the `log` method is to create a new object. Why have one floating around without being saved?

Comment: I agree, it's not a good way to do it, but I wanted to cover running instance methods in my answer too, since it seemed relevant to the confusion.

Comment: Okay, just making sure. I would include that it is not the preferred way, just to not confuse OP further.